# How to get privileges set for a report by obiee webservice or How to Judge a user whether have privilege to access a report?

Tags: obiee

I want to integrate obiee with MIS. I can view catalog of report through obiee's web service,and can explore reports.

The question is how to judge a user whether he has privileges to access a certain report? if he has, list the report. This is to say, I will list reports which a user has access privileges.

Please tell me the methods (by obiee web services),thanks!

Rockfiller(from changsha city,Hunan province,China)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: The whole sense of this site is to share questions & answers with the community so it is counterproductive to send answers by mail. I removed your mail address.

Answer (score 0):

This one:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e16364/methods.htm#i1010167

You will get:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e16364/methods.htm#i1010167
Which give you the ACL list.

No ?

Cheers
Nico